# jekyll - 'jekyll serve' generating done without server on

Tags: ruby, jekyll

When i enter the command:
    `jekyll serve` , 
i get following notice:
    `$ jekyll serve
    Configuration file: e:/workspace/soohu.github.com/_config.yml
             Source: e:/workspace/soohu.github.com
        Destination: e:/workspace/soohu.github.com/_site
        Generating...
                    done.`
and the jekyll stop, without server running.

I check the file`_site` and can see the static pages in it, and of course i can't view the site locally.
Does anybody know why?

thanks

Comment: This sounds like a bug. I'd raise it as an issue on the github repository.

Comment: You can have a look at [Run Jekyll on Windows](http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com)

Comment: Having the same problem in 2022 using latest Ruby (3.1.2p20) and Jekyll (4.2.2) on Windows 10

Comment: I'm having this with the dockerhub jekyll/builder:4.2.2 image.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and fixed by just appending `--force_polling` at the end of `jekyll serve`, aka `jekyll serve --force_polling`.

For detail, please refer to this issue ['jekyll serve' generating done without server on](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2933).

Comment: This is the answer - and works with jekyll/builder:4.2.2 container image.